# How do I make RoR select option name and id concatenations of other fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, menu, concatenation, html-select

I”m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have a relation that returns certain columns …

```
MyObject.joins(:distance_unit)
    .where(["user_id = ?", user.id])
    .select("distance, distance_units.id, distance_units.abbrev")
```

This data is meant to be used in a select menu …

```
<%= select_tag "distance", options_from_collection_for_select(@distance_options, "distance", "distance") %>
```

However, what I want is for the id to be a concatenation of the “distance” and “distance_units.id” fields and the option name to be a concatenation of the “distance” and “distance_unit.abbrev” fields.  How do I do that in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can do it with options_for_select, like this:

  ```
  <%= select_tag "distance", options_for_select(@distance_options.collect{|obj| ["#{obj.distance}_#{obj.id}", "#{obj.distance}_#{obj.abbrev}"]}) %>
  ```

Comment: In my query though, I'm only selecting two columns, each from different database tables, so there is no model encapsulating both of those.  How do I do the concatenation given those conditions?